# How to programmatically get documentMode from IHTMLDocument?

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, ihtmldocument2

I use a WebBrowser control in a C++ application and would like to retrieve the [documentMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a loaded document.

The IHTMLDocument2 interface has methods for specific properties ([get_domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa752575), [get_charset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa752566%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [get_readyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa752602%28v=VS.85%29), ...) but none for [documentMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there a generic method to get a property by its name or an other method that I can use to get that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QI for IHTMLDocument6, then call IHTMLDocument6::get_documentMode.
You can also use late binding (QI for IDispatchEx, then Invoke).

Comment: IHTMLDocument6 was not in the SDK (6.0A) I was using. That's why I haven't found it. Thanks.